# Gitlab CI does not support variable expansion in needs keyword, is there any solution?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I'm creating a `template` for all the deploy jobs, and I need to be able to use `needs` keyword with different values for each deploy job, but GitLab CI, as far as I know, does not support using variable in `needs` keyword. Is there any workaround?

This is what I need to do:

```
# Deploy template
.deploy:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - develop
  tags:
    - deploy
  needsL ["build:$PROJECT_NAME"]


# Deploy jobs

deploy:package1:
  extends: .deploy
  variables:
    PROJECT_NAME: 'package1'
  #needs: ['build:package1']

deploy:package2:
  extends: .deploy
  variables:
    PROJECT_NAME: 'package2'
  #needs: ['build:package2']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this. `needs:` will not support variables.

However, if the template you're making does not contain the job it depends on, the best approach is probably to not use `needs:` at all, otherwise you greatly increase the likelihood that including your template will cause an invalid yaml file.

So, your options would be either to (1) include the jobs you depend on in the same template, then designate `needs:` explicitly or (2) Rely on users to provide the `needs:` key in the deploy job if they want.

For example, a user can do this:

```
include:
  - "your template"

# job originates in the project configuration
my_project_jobs:
  script: "..."


your_deploy_template_job:
  needs: ["my_project_job"]  # add the key to the included template job
```

Or if you provide both jobs in your pipeline configuration, you can use some `rules:` to keep the jobs from running, and let users enable them and override their script configurations to implement builds.

```yaml
# your template yaml
your_template_build_job:package1
  rules:
    - if: '$PACKAGE1_ENABLED'
      when: on_success
    - when: never


your_template_deploy_job:package1
  rules:
    - if: '$PACKAGE1_ENABLED'
  needs: [your_template_build_job:package1]
  # ...
```

Then a user might just do this:

```yaml
# user project yaml
include:
  - "your template"

variables:
  PACKAGE1_ENABLED: true

your_template_build_job:package1
  script: "my project build script"
```

When the user doesn't explicitly enable a job, neither the build nor deploy job will be in the pipeline configuration. However, they only need to enable the build job (by variable) and the `needs:` configuration for the deploy job will already be in place.

Neither of these approaches are particularly perfect for very flexible use of templates, unfortunately. But there may be another option...

### Workaround: Dynamic child pipelines

As a possible workaround, users could use [dynamic child pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/parent_child_pipelines.html#dynamic-child-pipelines) to generate an entire pipeline configuration with correct `needs:` based on a minimal configuration. Almost anything is possible with dynamic child pipelines because you can generate the YAML programmatically on-the-fly, though, it may be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Is there any reason that needs can't/wont support variables?

Answer (score 0):

To anyone that still comes across this thread, there does now seem to be a solution that is working for me to use variables in the `needs` keyword(supported as of v15.11, currently on v16.7.6 when writing this).  It requires the use of [inputs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/inputs.html#use-includeinputs-with-multiple-files).  In my workflow, I have, "build-{env}-image", "deploy-{env}", dast_scan(manual), and "stop-{env}" jobs.  {env} changes with the branch name.  Each job needs the previous to ensure proper workflow and to allow the stop job to run in case the team didn't need to run dast_scan.

First, I setup the [spec header](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#spec) as follows:

```
spec:
  inputs:
    env:
      default: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"

---

{Rest of yaml file}
```

The job names are then defined as follows:

```
build_$[[ inputs.env | expand_vars ]]_image:
  stage: build
  script:
    - "Build image script"
```

The `| expand_vars` is only required if you are using variables in the spec like I have above.  GitLab's docs talk more about the ability to use functions to manipulate strings as needed.

The other jobs with "needs" has to use the needs:job syntax in order to use the inputs.  This doesn't seem to work with the `needs: ["job_name"]` syntax.

```
deploy_$[[ inputs.env | expand_vars ]]:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - "Deploy script"
  needs:
    - job: build_$[[ inputs.env | expand_vars ]]_image
```

I hope this helps anybody else.  It took me a while to find and properly implement this like I want.

Last note:  The "inputs" feature also works with the `environment:on_stop` keyword.

```
deploy_$[[ inputs.env | expand_vars ]]:
  environment:
    name: $ENVIRONMENT_NAME
    on_stop: stop_$[[ inputs.branch-slug | expand_vars ]]

stop_$[[ inputs.env | expand_vars ]]:
  environment:
    name: $ENVIRONMENT_NAME
    action: stop
```